What is the difference between a final draft and a final version?
Am I right that:
Since a draft is a rough version, then a final draft is a final rough version. That means a final draft implies you will submit it to someone and he may not approve it and ask to work it out one more time.
A final version does not have the connotation that someone will check it.

What is your native language?// At the end of writing drafts (first, second, etc), you get a first version of something and that could be the final one as well if no more changes are made to it. It depends on the process where you work or for whom you work. BUT: final rough version is not used in this lingo. Unless you use that term instead of draft. I am sure these differences exist in most languages.

Note, while the word "draft" alone can mean "rough version," especially when contrasted with other words, it can just mean "version," as in "first draft, second draft," etc. Thus some contexts might use "final draft" simply to mean "final version." Also, not all processes involve someone else approving your work. A personal letter, for instance, might go through drafts if it were important.

Draft may mean a rough version but in places where drafts count (offices and organizations), no one would say a rough version. They'd say a rough draft. It's funny because I worked on/in publications with Brits for years and this is all standard fare in BrE and AmE.

It depends to some extent what it's a draft of. Draft has different meanings in screenwriting and architecture for instance. Please explain your specific problem.

They would pretty much mean the same thing.  When working on an essay (for example) you create a first draft.  You improve, edit or rewrite, that is your second draft.  You improve the second draft, and that is the third draft.  Eventually you reach the point at which you make no more improvements.  That draft is therefore your final draft.
But the final draft is the one which you will submit to be marked ( or sent or published etc)
There is no suggestion or implication that an external editor or checker must be involved.  It may well be that the final draft/final version will then be checked by someone else, who will suggest more changes, in which case the version that you thought was the final draft, wasn't.  In fact you will only know that a draft was the "final" one, when it is submitted or published.
